# Find the point of intersection of two linear equations using Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, least-squares, polynomials, data-fitting

The objective is to find the point of intersection of two linear equations. These two linear equation are derived using the Numpy `polyfit` functions.

Given two time series (`xLeft`, `yLeft`) and (`xRight`, `yRight`), the linear least suqares fit to each of them was calculated using `polyfit` as shown below:

```
xLeft = [
    6168, 6169, 6170, 6171, 6172, 6173, 6174, 6175, 6176, 6177,
    6178, 6179, 6180, 6181, 6182, 6183, 6184, 6185, 6186, 6187
]
yLeft = [
    0.98288751, 1.3639959, 1.7550986, 2.1539073, 2.5580614,
    2.9651523, 3.3727503, 3.7784295, 4.1797948, 4.5745049,
    4.9602985, 5.3350167, 5.6966233, 6.0432272, 6.3730989,
    6.6846867, 6.9766307, 7.2477727, 7.4971657, 7.7240791
]

xRight = [
    6210, 6211, 6212, 6213, 6214, 6215, 6216, 6217, 6218, 6219,
    6220, 6221, 6222, 6223, 6224, 6225, 6226, 6227, 6228, 6229,
    6230, 6231, 6232, 6233, 6234, 6235, 6236, 6237, 6238, 6239,
    6240, 6241, 6242, 6243, 6244, 6245, 6246, 6247, 6248, 6249,
    6250, 6251, 6252, 6253, 6254, 6255, 6256, 6257, 6258, 6259,
    6260, 6261, 6262, 6263, 6264, 6265, 6266, 6267, 6268, 6269,
    6270, 6271, 6272, 6273, 6274, 6275, 6276, 6277, 6278, 6279,
    6280, 6281, 6282, 6283, 6284, 6285, 6286, 6287, 6288]
yRight=[
    7.8625913, 7.7713094, 7.6833806, 7.5997391, 7.5211883,
    7.4483986, 7.3819046, 7.3221073, 7.2692747, 7.223547,
    7.1849418, 7.1533613, 7.1286001, 7.1103559,  7.0982385,
    7.0917811, 7.0904517, 7.0936642, 7.100791, 7.1111741,
    7.124136, 7.1389918, 7.1550579, 7.1716633, 7.1881566,
    7.2039142, 7.218349, 7.2309117, 7.2410989, 7.248455,
    7.2525721, 7.2530937, 7.249711, 7.2421637, 7.2302341,
    7.213747, 7.1925621, 7.1665707, 7.1356878, 7.0998487,
    7.0590014, 7.0131001, 6.9621005, 6.9059525, 6.8445964,
    6.7779589, 6.7059474, 6.6284504, 6.5453324, 6.4564347,
    6.3615761, 6.2605534, 6.1531439, 6.0391097, 5.9182019,
    5.7901659, 5.6547484, 5.5117044, 5.360805, 5.2018456,
    5.034656, 4.8591075, 4.6751242, 4.4826899, 4.281858,
    4.0727611, 3.8556159, 3.6307325, 3.3985188, 3.1594861,
    2.9142516, 2.6635408, 2.4081881, 2.1491354, 1.8874279,
    1.6242117,1.3607255,1.0982931,0.83831298
]

left_line = np.polyfit(xleft, yleft, 1)
right_line = np.polyfit(xRight, yRight, 1)
```

In this case, `polyfit` outputs the coeficients `m` and `b` for `y = mx + b`, respectively.

The intersection of the two linear equations then can be calculated as follows:

```
x0 = -(left_line[1] - right_line[1]) / (left_line[0] - right_line[0])
y0 = x0 * left_line[0] + left_line[1]
```

However, I wonder whether there exist Numpy build-in approach to calculate the last two steps?

Comment: This seems to be a straightforward look-up in the NumPy documentation, not a Stack Overflow issue.

Comment: Hi @Prune thanks for dropping by. I have duly search the net but found nothing. Im asking here just in case I miss some keyword. Appreciate if you can share some relevant keyword in the comment. This may help me refine the search

Comment: Look into scipy or better yet, sympy for this. Another approach you can take is to subtract one line off the other (correctly though), and find the root of the remainder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly a built-in approach, but you can simplify the problem. Say I have lines given my `y = m1 * x + b1` and `y = m2 * x + b2`. You can trivially find an equation for the difference, which is also a line:

```
y = (m1 - m2) * x + (b1 - b2)
```

Notice that this line will have a root at the intersection of the two original lines, if they intersect. You can use the [`numpy.polynomial.Polynomial`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial.html) class to perform these operations:

```
>>> (np.polynomial.Polynomial(left_line[::-1]) - np.polynomial.Polynomial(right_line[::-1])).roots()
array([6192.0710885])
```

Notice that I had to swap the order of the coefficients, since `Polynomial` expects smallest to largest, while [`np.polyfit`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html) returns the opposite. In fact, `np.polyfit` is not recommended. Instead, you can get `Polynomial` obejcts directly using [`np.polynomial.Polynomial.fit`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial.fit.html) class method. Your code would then look like:

```
left_line = np.polynomial.Polynomial.fit(xLeft, yLeft, 1, domain=[-1, 1])
right_line = np.polynomial.Polynomial.fit(xRight, yRight, 1, domain=[-1, 1])
x0 = (left_line - right_line).roots()
y0 = left_line(x0)
```

The `domain` is mapped to the window `[-1, 1]`. If you do not specify a `domain`, the peak-to-peak of the x-values will be used instead. You do not want this, since it will result in a mapping of the input values. Instead, we explicitly specify that the domain `[-1, 1]` maps to the same window. An alternative would be to use the default domain and set e.g. `window=[xLeft.min(), xLeft.max()]`. The problem with this approach is that it would then create different domains for the polynomials, preventing the operation `left_line - right_line`.

See https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.polynomials.classes.html for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the detail explanation @Mad, however, running your suggestion give an error `TypeError: Domains differ`.

Comment: Also, I have not disclose it earlier the main reason of using Numpy `polyfit` is because, apart from the  linear equation, I also interested to extract the `mean` and std` value. While I have yet how to achieve this using the Numpy `polyfit`. But I know the MATLAB `polyfit` can produce both the `mean` and `std`.

Comment: @balandongiv I assure you that if you read the docs carefully, you will be able to do both much more simply with the `Polynomial` class than an array of coefficients. If you need the array of coefficients, you can get that directly from a `Polynomial` object as well, so I am not sure what your concern is. If you have a specific question, feel free to ask it. If you ping me, I will attempt to answer.

Comment: Hi Mad, I have initiate the chat on SO-chat

Comment: @balandongiv. Fixed. see update. You have to explicitly slam in an identical domain while fitting to avoid remapping issues.

Comment: Thanks for the update @Mad, Btw, I still not clear why you explicitly not recommended `np.polyfit`, at least in this case?

Comment: @balandongiv. Because you might want to do other stuff with the result or data, and the fit is going to be at least as good

Comment: Speaking of better fit, let me revisit domain one more time

Comment: IIUC, the output of polynomial is rich in information?

Comment: @balandongiv. The data is better organized, easier to debug, and has a bunch of methods to do the stuff you wanted out of the box. That was the whole point of this question to begin with, no?

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. Thanks for introducing this new stuff

Comment: Btw @Mad, if you dont mind to share your thought about the OP : https://stackoverflow.com/q/68189585/6446053 . This is continuation from the OP here.

Answer (score 1):

You can model it as a linear system and use simple linear algebra:

```
def get_intersection(m1,b1,m2,b2):
    A = np.array([[-m1, 1], [-m2, 1]])
    b = np.array([[b1], [b2]])
    # you have to solve linear System AX = b where X = [x y]'
    X = np.linalg.pinv(A) @ b
    x, y = np.round(np.squeeze(X), 4)
    return x, y # returns point of intersection (x,y) with 4 decimal precision

m1,b1,m2,b2 = left_line(0), left_line(1), right_line(0), right_line(1)
print(get_intersection(m1,b1,m2,b2))
```

As an example, for lines y - x = 1, and y + x = 1, we expect the intersection as (0,1):

```
m1,b1,m2,b2 = 1, 1, -1, 1
print(get_intersection(m1,b1,m2,b2))
```

Output: `(0.0, 1.0)` as expected.

Comment: Seems like a bit of overkill for the instersection of two lines, no?