# Dissimilarity between the output of linear equation produced by Numpy Polynomial and Matlab polyfit

Tags: python, numpy, matlab, least-squares, polynomials

The objective is to find the coefficients of a polynomial `P(x)` of degree `1` (a line) that fits the data `y` best in a least-squares sense, and then compute the root of `P`.

In Matlab, the linear least squares fit can be calculated via

```
[p, S, mu] = polyfit(x, y, 1)
```

This produces the coefficients `p`, which define the polynomial:

```
-1.5810877
6.0094824

y = p(1) * x + p(2)
```

[mu](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyfit.html#d123e1032209) represents the `mean` and `std` of the `x`.

In Python, this can be achieved via the Numpy's `polynomial` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68182478/6446053):

```
import numpy as np

x = [
    6210, 6211, 6212, 6213, 6214, 6215, 6216, 6217, 6218, 6219,
    6220, 6221, 6222, 6223, 6224, 6225, 6226, 6227, 6228, 6229,
    6230, 6231, 6232, 6233, 6234, 6235, 6236, 6237, 6238, 6239,
    6240, 6241, 6242, 6243, 6244, 6245, 6246, 6247, 6248, 6249,
    6250, 6251, 6252, 6253, 6254, 6255, 6256, 6257, 6258, 6259,
    6260, 6261, 6262, 6263, 6264, 6265, 6266, 6267, 6268, 6269,
    6270, 6271, 6272, 6273, 6274, 6275, 6276, 6277, 6278, 6279,
    6280, 6281, 6282, 6283, 6284, 6285, 6286, 6287, 6288
]
y = [
    7.8625913, 7.7713094, 7.6833806, 7.5997391, 7.5211883,
    7.4483986, 7.3819046, 7.3221073, 7.2692747, 7.223547,
    7.1849418, 7.1533613, 7.1286001, 7.1103559,  7.0982385,
    7.0917811, 7.0904517, 7.0936642, 7.100791, 7.1111741,
    7.124136, 7.1389918, 7.1550579, 7.1716633, 7.1881566,
    7.2039142, 7.218349, 7.2309117, 7.2410989, 7.248455,
    7.2525721, 7.2530937, 7.249711, 7.2421637, 7.2302341,
    7.213747, 7.1925621, 7.1665707, 7.1356878, 7.0998487,
    7.0590014, 7.0131001, 6.9621005, 6.9059525, 6.8445964,
    6.7779589, 6.7059474, 6.6284504, 6.5453324, 6.4564347,
    6.3615761, 6.2605534, 6.1531439, 6.0391097, 5.9182019,
    5.7901659, 5.6547484, 5.5117044, 5.360805, 5.2018456,
    5.034656, 4.8591075, 4.6751242, 4.4826899, 4.281858,
    4.0727611, 3.8556159, 3.6307325, 3.3985188, 3.1594861,
    2.9142516, 2.6635408, 2.4081881, 2.1491354, 1.8874279,
    1.6242117,1.3607255,1.0982931,0.83831298
]

p = np.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial.fit(x, y, 1, domain=[-1, 1])
print(p)
```

```
436.53467443432453 - 0.0688950539698132·x¹
```

Both the `mean` and `std` can be calculated as follows:

```
x_mean = np.mean(x)
x_std = np.std(x)
```

I notice however, the coefficients produce by Matlab's `polyfit` and the Numpy's `Polynomial` are different:

MATLAB: `[-1.5810877, 6.0094824]` vs Python: `[436.53467443432453, 0.0688950539698132]`

The difference is significant for my use-case, because I want to compute the roots of the line.

In Matlab, this can be calculates as

```
>> x_m = p(1);
>> x_mean = mu(1);
>> x_c = p(2);
>> x_std = mu(2);
>> x_intercept = (x_m * x_mean - x_c * x_std) ./ x_m
x_intercept = 
    6336.2266
```

Whereas in Python

```
>>> x_mean = np.mean(x)
>>> x_std = np.std(x)
>>> x_c, x_m = line.coef
>>> x_intercept = (x_m * x_mean - x_c * x_std) / x_m
>>> x_intercept
150737.19742902054
```

Clearly, the difference between these two is big. How can I replicate the `x_intercept` calculated using Matlab in Python?

Comment: Using `np.linalg.lstsq` or `OLS` from `statsmodels` givens me the same regression coefficients as your Python `polyfit` code. I would double-check the Matlab calculation.

Comment: Hi @hilberts_drinking_problem, thanks for your time looking at this issue.

Comment: I have matlab available, so will check

Comment: I think you may be missing the point of mu in matlab (which is the same as domain in numpy). I'll write up an answer momentarily

Comment: Thanks for the time joining the discussion here @Mad. In Matlab, x = x(:); mu = [mean(x); std(x)]; Also available: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyfit.html#d123e1032209 . Based on this, I assume we can calculate both mean and std using the numpy build function? Or do I misunderstand something here?

Comment: @balandongiv. I've posted an exhaustive answer that hopefully clears everything up

Comment: I've edited your question a bit, but your initial statement `y = p(1) * x + p(2)` is wrong if you get `mu` as part of the output. Hopefully it's clear why, and what the differences between `mu` in matlab and `domain` in python are now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the sake of numerical precision, it is handy to map polynomial data to the domain `[-1, 1]` or some similarly well-bounded region when computing fits. A classic example is given in the numpy [docs regarding fitting Chebyshev polynomials](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.polynomials.classes.html#fitting), which appear to lose all their interesting features if you zoom out far enough. The mapping is less interesting for lines, but highly useful for higher order polynomials, where `x**n` may explode. The specific window `[-1, 1]` is used exactly to prevent such explosions for arbitrarily shifted data with large `n` (since `+/-1**n` is always just `+/-1`, and `x**n` for `|x| < 1` is always well bounded).

Let's start by looking at the data (which is always a good first step):

[image]

I've included a line fit here. Just by eye, I can tell that a root at ~6340 is reasonable for the line fit. It's also pretty clear that the data is actually more cubic in nature, with an "actual" root around 6290, but that's irrelevant to the question.

MATLAB takes the approach of mapping the x-data such that the 1-sigma portion of the domain fits within the window `[-1, 1]`. That means that the polynomial coefficients you get apply to `(x - mean(xRight)) / std(xRight)`. If you choose to do [scaling](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyfit.html#d123e1032209), by requesting three output arguments from [`polyfit`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyfit.html), you do not have the option of choosing a different scale:

```matlab
>> [p_scaled, s, m] = polyfit(xRight, yRight, 1)
p_scaled =
   -1.5811    6.0095
s = 
  struct with fields:
        R: [2×2 double]
       df: 77
    normr: 8.5045
m =
   1.0e+03 *
    6.2490
    0.0229

>> p_unscaled = polyfit(xRight, yRight, 1)
p_unscaled =
   -0.0689  436.5347
```

You can compute the values of both fits at say `x = 6250` using [`polyval`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyval.html):

```matlab
>> polyval(p_scaled, 6250, s, mu)
ans =
    5.9406

>> polyval(p_unscaled, 6250)
ans =
    5.9406

>> polyval(p_scaled, (6250 - mean(xRight)) / std(xRight))
ans =
    5.9406
```

And of course manually:

```matlab
>> (6250 - m(1)) / m(2) * p_scaled(1) + p_scaled(2)
ans =
    5.9406

>> 6250 * p_unscaled(1) + p_unscaled(2)
ans =
    5.9406
```

Python does something similar with the `domain` and `window` arguments to [`np.polynomial.Polynomial.fit`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial.fit.html). Just as MATLAB maps `[-std(x), std(x)] + mean(x)` to `[-1, 1]`, `domain` is mapped to `window`. The biggest difference is that you can choose both `domain` and `window`. Here are some common options:

```py
>>> p_nomap = np.polynomial.Polynomial.fit(xRight, yRight, 1, domain=[-1, 1]); print(p_nomap)
436.53467443435204 - 0.06889505396981752 x**1
>>> p_default = np.polynomial.Polynomial.fit(xRight, yRight, 1); print(p_default)
6.009482176962028 - 2.686907104822783 x**1
>>> p_minmax = np.polynomial.Polynomial.fit(xRight, yRight, 1, domain=[xRight_arr.min(), xRight_arr.max()]); print(p_minmax)
6.009482176962028 - 2.686907104822783 x**1
>>> p_matlab = np.polynomial.Polynomial.fit(xRight, yRight, 1, domain=np.std(xRight) * np.arange(-1, 2, 2) + np.mean(xRight)); print(p_matlab)
6.009482176962061 - 1.571048948945243 x**1
```

You can see the following equivalences:

- Numpy's `p_matlab` <=> MATLAB's `p_scaled`
- Numpy's `p_nomap` <=> MATLAB's `p_unscaled`
- Numpy's `p_minmax` <=> Numpy's `p_default`

You can verify with a similar test as in MATLAB, except that instead of `polyval`, you can just [call](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial.__call__.html) a [`Polynomial`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial.html) object directly:

```py
>>> p_nomap(6250)
5.940587122992554
>>> p_default(6250)
5.940587122992223
>>> p_minmax(6250)
5.940587122992223
>>> p_matlab(6250)
5.94058712299223
```

Python has a nicer syntax in this case, and since you are using an object, it keeps track of all the scales and offsets for you internally.

You can estimate the root of the line in any number of ways now that you understand how the different choices of `domain` work. In MATLAB:

```matlab
>> roots(p_unscaled)
ans =
   6.3362e+03
>> roots(p_scaled) * m(2) + m(1)
ans =
   6.3362e+03
>> -p_unscaled(2) / p_unscaled(1)
ans =
   6.3362e+03
>> -p_scaled(2) / p_scaled(1) * m(2) + m(1)
ans =
   6.3362e+03
```

You can do the same thing in numpy:

```py
>>> p_nomap.roots()
array([6336.22661252])
>>> p_default.roots()
array([6336.22661252])
>>> p_minmax.roots()
array([6336.22661252])
>>> p_matlab.roots()
array([6336.22661252])
```

To evaluate manually, we can use [`Polynomial.mapparms`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial.mapparms.html), which is roughly equivalent to the output parameter `m` in MATLAB. The major difference is that `mapparms` outputs `[-np.mean(xRight) / np.std(xRight), 1 / np.std(xRight)]`, which simplifies the evaluation process.

```py
>>> -p_nomap.coef[0] / p_nomap.coef[1]
6336.22661251699
>>> (-p_default.coef[0] / p_default.coef[1] - p_default.mapparms()[0]) / p_default.mapparms()[1]
6336.226612516987
>>> (-p_minmax.coef[0] / p_minmax.coef[1] - p_minmax.mapparms()[0]) / p_minmax.mapparms()[1]
6336.226612516987
>>> (-p_matlab.coef[0] / p_matlab.coef[1] - p_matlab.mapparms()[0]) / p_matlab.mapparms()[1]
6336.226612516987
```

So the key to getting equivalent results is to either choose identical parameters (and understand their correspondence), or to use the provided functions to evaluate polynomials and their roots. In general I recommend the latter regardless of the former. The reason those functions were provided is that you can get accurate results from any choice of `domain`, as long as you pass the data along consistently (manually for `polyval` and automatically for `Polynomial.__call__`)

Comment: Thanks @Mad for the extensive explanation. The elaboration indirectly sum up the query raise here https://stackoverflow.com/a/68182478/6446053]. +1 for the explanation of mapping to `domain`.

Comment: @balandongiv. It does. Now I'm thinking that if you were to use anything other than a line, your best bet for the other question would be something like `domain=[np.mininum(xRight.min(), xLeft.min()), np.maximum(xRight.max(), xLeft.max())]`